# element_to_bytes() function in pbc giving segmentation fault while using type i pairing

Tags: c, ubuntu, cryptography, gdb

So I was using **PBC 0.5.14** for developing a software for my research work. I need to use **type i** pairing for that. However, when I try to export elements using element_to_byte() function, it throws a segmentation fault. Later, I went on to check the size (using element_length_in_bytes()) of an element that I defined in group G1. It was shown to be zero. The code works perfectly fine if I replace **type i** pairing with **type a** pairing (which is also a symmetrical pairing in PBC). Below is the code snippet for which the fault is being shown.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "pbc-0.5.14/include/pbc.h"

pairing_t pairing;
char param[MAX_BUF];
unsigned char buffer[MAX_BUF];

element_t P;

void InitializePairing(){
    FILE* stream = fopen("pbc-0.5.14/param/i.param", "r");
    size_t count = fread(param, 1, MAX_BUF, stream);
    if(!count){
        printf("Input Error!!\n");
    }
    pairing_init_set_buf(pairing, param, count);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    InitializePairing();
    element_init_G1(P, pairing);
    element_random(P);
    printf("%d\n", element_length_in_bytes(P));
    element_to_bytes(buffer,P);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output from gdb backtrace.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x000000000040087e in element_to_bytes (data=0x6014a0 <buffer>    "", e=0x601080 <P>) at pbc-0.5.14/include/pbc_field.h:476
#2  0x000000000040096d in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdbe8) at    pbc_test_i.c:31
(gdb)
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in PBC

Answer (score 0):

The code reads:

```
static inline int element_to_bytes(unsigned char *data, element_t e) {
  return e->field->to_bytes(data, e);  // line 476
}
```

From this code and the crash stack, it is safe to conclude that `e->field == NULL`. The `e->field` is assigned in `element_init`:

```
static inline void element_init(element_t e, field_ptr f) {
  e->field = f;
  f->init(e);
}
```

which is called by `element_init_G1`. One must then conclude that the way you initialized `pairing` is wrong.

Note that `pairing_init_set_buf` may return an error, which you ignore (but shouldn't).

Comment: I checked the return value of "pairing_init_set_buf". It returns '0' which corresponds to success.